# Unlock/Lock device using DevicePolicyManager

Tags: java, android, device-admin

I am trying to make an app that automatically locks the screen to force it into sleep mode and reactivated it / unlock it at a specific time

I've managed to lock the screen using the DevicePolicyManager and making my app device admin,

policies.xml

```
    <?xml version= "1.0" encoding= "utf-8" ?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <uses-policies>
        <force-lock />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

to lock the screen i'm using a button

```
     DevicePolicyManager deviceManger ;
public void lockPhone (View view) {
      deviceManger.lockNow() ;
    }
```

I am using an android TV box , the screen gets locked and goes into idle mode .

How can I unlock it again programmatically without pressing the power button on the remote.